# function names conflict in C++

Tags: c++, conflict

Class B inherits from Class A. Class A have a virtual function named `bind`.

```
Class A {
  virtual void bind();
}

class B: public A {
  B();
}
```

In the constructor of B, it uses `bind (int __fd, __CONST_SOCKADDR_ARG __addr, socklen_t __len)` function from `<sys/socket.h>`.

```
#include <sys/socket.h>

B::B () {
  int sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
  sockaddr_in server_addr, client_addr;
  if(sockfd < 0)
    perror("ERROR opening socket.\n");
  bzero((char*)&server_addr, sizeof(server_addr));
  server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
  server_addr.sin_port = 2333;
  if(bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&server_addr, sizeof(server_addr)) < 0)
    perror("ERROR on binding.\n");
  listen(sockfd, 1);
}
```

Compilers throws errors saying that the two `bind` functions conflict. I know that I can create a wrapper for `bind` in `sys/socket.h`. Is there any elegant and easier ways to resolve the conflict?

Thanks

Comment: you should try ::bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&server_addr, sizeof(server_addr) to access global bind

Comment: Read more about `scope resolution operator` http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_resolution_operator

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Just qualify the call:

```
if (::bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&server_addr, sizeof(server_addr)) < 0)
//  ^^
```

This will tell the compiler to look for a function called `bind` in the global namespace - I am assuming that `bind()` does live in the global namespace; if it does not, then you should specify the name of the namespace where it lives before the scope resolution operator (`::`).